# generate file name list for a given folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a list of document saved in a folder, I need to save the file name along with its path in a plain text file, such as

```
/document/file1.txt
/document/file2.txt
...
```

My question is how to iterate through a file folder and extract the path information for each file. Thanks.

Comment: using `glob.glob("/document/*.txt")` ? can you be more specific

Comment: Or even something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory? It's not clear what your stumbling block is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this.

```
import os
output_file = open(filename, 'w')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        f = print(os.path.join(root, name))
        output_file.write(f)
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
output_file.close()
```

you can also use `listdir()` method

```
file = open(filename, 'w')
    for f in os.listdir(dirName):
        f = os.path.join(dirName, f)
        file.write(f)
 file.close()
```